# Compiler isn't handling freertos #define code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, rtos, freertos

I'm just trying to load the demo code into my RX62N, but the code doesn't compile. I get a lot of errors exactly like this one.

> Error[Pe125]: expected a "(" C:\FreeRTOSV7.4.2\FreeRTOS\Source\queue.c 263

Which links here

```
if( xTaskRemoveFromEventList( &( pxQueue->xTasksWaitingToSend ) ) == pdTRUE )
{
    portYIELD_WITHIN_API();
}
```

and is defined like this

```
#ifndef portYIELD_WITHIN_API
    #define portYIELD_WITHIN_API portYIELD
#endif
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize now that I left a lot of stuff out of the question, but I've solved it. The demo code I tried to load was for the RSK not the RDK(which I have). Also the IDE was too old to load the correct workspace.

Once I did those two things it loaded and compiled successfully.